# opkg.conf file: src vs src/gz

Tags: linux, opkg

I am looking at different opkg.conf examples on the web and would like a better understanding of the tool and configuration file format.

What is the difference between `src` and `src/gz` in the following examples?

1. `src/gz snapshots http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/packages`
2. `src snapshots http://download.geexbox.org/snapshots/geexbox-xbmc-imx6-cuboxi/latest/binaries.cuboxi/packages/`

Where can I find more information about the various options in the config?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src/gz` will download `Packages.gz` from the specified URL

`src` will download `Packages` from the specified URL